# include method from multiple class

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance

I have this question asked once and still not sure about this.
Suppose we have two class

```
class A { public void a(){} }
class B { public void b(){} }
```

now I want to access both methods a() and b() from class C . How to do so.
Is composition is the answer?

Comment: `A.a()` and `B.b()`? Those are `static` methods.

Answer (score 4):

Since `A.a` and `B.b` are `static`, you can just call them.

```
class C {
    void foo() {
        A.a();
        B.b();
    }
}
```

You don't 'include' them, a concept unkown to Java.

**Edit**

Since now you have removed `static`, call the methods on instances.

```
class C {
    void foo() {
        new A().a();
        new B().b();
    }
}
```

Java does not support multiple inheritance, no traits, and no mixins.

Comment: @Luzt : I know this can be done for static. This was just an example. I want to know for non static methods what will be the case? Let me edit that example. by include  I meant include the behavior of class A and B.

Comment: Why don't you ask this then?